# Understanding of Matrix and Linear Map Question

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a question in Linear Algebra Done Right and I somehow didn't understand what's it's asking. Since, this type of question has been asked in multiple source, I want to understand it better. Hope this question not out of context in this forum.

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T$ $\epsilon$
> $L(V,W)$. Prove that there exists a basis of V and a basis of W such
> that with respect to these bases, all entries of $M(T)$ are $0$ except
> that the entries in row $j$, column $j$, equal 1 for 1
> $\stackrel{}{\le}$ $j$ $\stackrel{}{\le}$ dim range $T$.

Thanks!

Comment: The matrix representation of a linear map depends on the bases of the domain and codomain. Are there bases of the domain and codomain such that the matrix representation of a given map looks like the one given in the question? That's what it's asking (or rather, to show why the answer is yes).

Comment: For example, if $\dim V = 6$, $\dim W=4$ and $\dim \operatorname{range} T = 3$, then you need to find bases for $V$ and $W$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to this bases looks like $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks @azif00 & @Vercassivelaunos! Just to confirm, do I need to find the complete basis of W as well? Because basis of W is $Tv_k$ plus some other basis of W.

Comment: @Beta Well, if you find a basis for $\operatorname{range} T$, then you can say that that basis can be extended to a basis for the whole $W$ without giving the explicit construction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!